# Extreme sound lag (chrome)

Tags: sound, google-chrome

This issue occurs every time i watch a video.
I can only say that it happens on chrome, because i currently didn't test it on another browser yet:

At first, the sound is in place with the video. However when i jump to another place in the video the sound from the old place continues for ~7-10 sec before being synchronized with the new part of the video.
The strangest thing is, that even if i close the tab or even the program, the sound from the video continues playing.
Also, the GPU utilisation is at 48%, although i have an NVidia GEforce GTX 860m and flash player normally consumes much less resources.
This problem just appeared without me changing anything, and it never happened before.

I think this problem is related to ubuntu or my hardware rather then chrome since, as i already said, the sound continues after the program is closed.
Thank you for any advice,
This.foo

Comment: Well Chrome runs in the background all the time, so it's possible that it's Chrome or Ubuntu. When did you last reboot?

Comment: 2 times after experiencing the problem. It's still there

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable` and then reinstall Chrome from their website.

Comment: Ok, did just that. Also used the possibility to try it out in firefox. Turns out it's a problem in firefox to. and reinstalling chrome didn't help.

Comment: Then it's Ubuntu itself. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 16 GB (i think that's a bit more then enough)

Comment: Definitely. Open `System Monitor` and see if anything is using excessive amounts of RAM/

Comment: no. 1.6 Gb are currently in use. Also, i remember now that i did change something concerning sound, in HDAanalyzer to get my built in subwoofer working(see https://superuser.com/questions/945110/how-do-i-make-my-lenovo-y50s-subwoofer-work-on-linux). But upon every system restart the settings reset themself, and you can only change which pins are on/off. Theres nothing concerning sound quality or the likes there, so i'm pretty sure it's not HDAanalyzer causing problems.

Comment: This is weird. You can try removing the PulseAudio config files (delete ~/.config/pulse*)

Comment: wow. it actually worked. Please  post this as an answer so i can accept it (you'll get reputation )  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had a problem with audio too. What fixed it for me was to remove the PulseAudio configuration files. Delete the folder named `Pulse*` under `~/.config`.